# Getting : error while evaluating conditional (my_result.stat.exists): 'bool object' has no attribute 'stat' while expcting to be dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i have this ansible simple playbook :
where "/home/ec2-user/test1.txt" exists on disk

```
---
- name: check if exsist
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - name: Get project name
      shell: "echo 'hhhhhhhh'"
      register: name_var


    - name: Check if thetest.log exists in path
      stat:
        path: "/home/ec2-user/test1.txt1"
      register: log_result_1

    - name: Check if TheTest.log exists in p_home
      stat:
        path: "/home/ec2-user/test1.txt"
      register: log_result_2
      when: name_var.stdout is match("hhhhhhhh")

    - set_fact:
        my_result: "{{ log_result_1.stat.exists or (log_result_2 is not skipped and log_result_2.stat.exists) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "#################################### result_value ######################################"
    - debug:
        var: my_result


    - name: Create temporary log folder
      file:
        path: "/home/ec2-user/log_tmp"
        state: directory
      when: my_result.stat.exists
```

I expect that the my_result will have the value of the right register in this case log_result_2

but I'm getting this error:

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.7
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ec2-user/venv_ansible_new/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ec2-user/venv_ansible_new/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAYBOOK: test3.yml *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in test3.yml

PLAY [check if exsist] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Get project name] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test3.yml:7
Tuesday 05 May 2020  09:56:22 +0000 (0:00:00.070)       0:00:00.070 ***********
changed: [localhost] => changed=true
  cmd: echo 'hhhhhhhh'
  delta: '0:00:00.002594'
  end: '2020-05-05 09:56:22.684370'
  rc: 0
  start: '2020-05-05 09:56:22.681776'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: hhhhhhhh
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [Check if thetest.log exists in path] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test3.yml:12
Tuesday 05 May 2020  09:56:22 +0000 (0:00:00.256)       0:00:00.327 ***********
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  stat:
    exists: false

TASK [Check if TheTest.log exists in p_home] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test3.yml:17
Tuesday 05 May 2020  09:56:22 +0000 (0:00:00.250)       0:00:00.577 ***********
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  stat:
    atime: 1588660417.6106787
    attr_flags: ''
    attributes: []
    block_size: 4096
    blocks: 8
    charset: us-ascii
    checksum: 75bae7e3ee07809acd2477a8427b5b32e605a6b4
    ctime: 1588660417.6106787
    dev: 66305
    device_type: 0
    executable: false
    exists: true
    gid: 1000
    gr_name: ec2-user
    inode: 77678
    isblk: false
    ischr: false
    isdir: false
    isfifo: false
    isgid: false
    islnk: false
    isreg: true
    issock: false
    isuid: false
    mimetype: text/plain
    mode: '0664'
    mtime: 1588660417.6106787
    nlink: 1
    path: /home/ec2-user/test1.txt
    pw_name: ec2-user
    readable: true
    rgrp: true
    roth: true
    rusr: true
    size: 18
    uid: 1000
    version: '1015088889'
    wgrp: true
    woth: false
    writeable: true
    wusr: true
    xgrp: false
    xoth: false
    xusr: false

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test3.yml:23
Tuesday 05 May 2020  09:56:23 +0000 (0:00:00.188)       0:00:00.765 ***********
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    my_result: true

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test3.yml:26
Tuesday 05 May 2020  09:56:23 +0000 (0:00:00.030)       0:00:00.796 ***********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '#################################### result_value ######################################'

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test3.yml:28
Tuesday 05 May 2020  09:56:23 +0000 (0:00:00.011)       0:00:00.808 ***********
ok: [localhost] =>
  my_result: true

TASK [Create temporary log folder] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test3.yml:32
Tuesday 05 May 2020  09:56:23 +0000 (0:00:00.010)       0:00:00.819 ***********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The conditional check 'my_result.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (my_result.stat.exists): 'bool object' has no attribute 'stat'

    The error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/test3.yml': line 32, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:


        - name: Create temporary log folder
          ^ here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the temporary folder creation task like below:

```
- name: Create temporary log folder
  file:
    path: "/home/ec2-user/log_tmp"
    state: directory
  when: my_result
```

`my_result` is already set to a boolean value by the `set_fact` task. This is what you can do to set the actual dictionary instead of boolean.

```
- set_fact:
    my_result: "{% if log_result_1.stat.exists %} {{ log_result_1 }} {% elif log_result_2 is not skipped and log_result_2.stat.exists %} {{ log_result_2 }} {% endif %}"
```

Comment: set_fact can hold the dictionary ref not boolean value?
i mean a copy of the register?

Comment: Sure, you can set the actual dictionary too by changing the set_fact. Added code to my answer.

Comment: getting error with the new:
Tuesday 05 May 2020  11:24:24 +0000 (0:00:00.028)       0:00:00.832 ***********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The conditional check 'my_result' failed. The error was: Invalid conditional detected: unexpected indent (<unknown>, line 1)

    The error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/test3.yml': line 31, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:


        - name: Create temporary log folder
          ^ here

Comment: To indent the condition and break it to multiple lines you can change `my_result` registration like `my_result: |` or `my_result: >` then condition starts from the next line with one more level of indentation. Check [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) for more details.